# ActiveAdmin belongs_to for 'foreign_key' association column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, belongs-to

I had problem in AA with two resources Organization and FG_Value, FG_Value contains column group_unit which could be organization_id. So I would like to display fg_values of 'xyz' organization.
I defined routes:

```
resources :organizations do 
  resources :focus_group_values
end
```

and in organization there is action

```
item 'Focus Group Values', organization_focus_group_values_path(organization)
```

I used belongs_to, but still I got all fg values, not filtered for xyz and in the log there is:

```
Processing by FocusGroupValuesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"organization_id"=>"xyz"}
SELECT  "focus_group_values".* FROM "focus_group_values"...
```

and the routes are:

```
organization_focus_group_values_path    GET /organizations/:organization_id/focus_group_values(.:format)    
focus_group_values#index
```

```
ActiveAdmin.register Organization do
end
```

```
ActiveAdmin.register FocusGroupValue do
   belongs_to :feedback
   belongs_to :organization
end
```

I tried use in organization

```
belongs_to :organization, param: :group_unit, optional: true
```

but without success. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: I would look into the sourcecode of the FocusGroupValuesController. Do you have access to that? If so, could you add it to the post?

Comment: Ahoj Jano :-). Are you building your app only using Active Admin or are you purposefully mixing Rails app (with defined routes, controllers and views) with Active Admin?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add your own routes for active admin resources. Just delete your additional routes, and your configuration to accessing FG_value only for 'xyz' organization will work out of the box..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I updated my question,I didn't consider it important, but it was. I had two `belongs_to` in ActiveAdmin FocusGroupValue. And that was the main issue, because it took only the first one. I put them to the FocusGroupValuesController and then updated organization model with association 
`has_many :focus_group_values, foreign_key: :group_unit, inverse_of: :organization` and now I can get all FG values for organization 'xyz'.